# Перенос новостей

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет, сделал небольшую систему новостей на PHP но возникла проблема.
На странице отображения новостей всё криво:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но хотелось бы чтобы они были все в вертикальном положении. Помогите пожалуйста)

```
<section>
            <div class="row">
                                <?
                                    global $db;
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id";
                                    $result = $db->query($sql);

                                    for($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++)
                                    {
                                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                                        echo '
                                        <div class="col-md-6" style="left: 350px;">
                                        <div class="box box-primary">
                                        <div class="box-body" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <img style="width: 604px; height: 320px;" src="'.$row['img'].'"></img>
                                        <h6>'.$row['headline'].'</h6>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>';
                                    }
                                ?>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Вставь <br /> там, где надо. br это перевод строки.

Comment: Измени `col-md-6` на `col-md-12`

Comment: @xverizex br не помогает

Comment: @Anton Kucenko вам спасибо) помогли